# Get FormData from request in API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I want to create an API which takes the form data as input and pass it to another API, but I am not able fetch that formdata from the request. please help me with this.

Here is the code of my API

```
router.post('/file', async (req, res) => {
  const { file } = req.body;
  try {
    const url = `${API_URL}/api/file/upload`;
    const response = await axios.get(url, file);

    res.json({ status: true, data: response.data });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ status: false, error: 'Error in uploading' });
  }
});
```

Here is the screenshot of data I want to sent by the postman

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The key is how the variable in body is named.
If you are trying to make file upload i would recommend [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload)
You can get the file buffer from that.
Then you can use [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) to upload it somewhere else.

```
router.use(require(`express-fileupload`)());
router.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    var FormData = require('form-data');
    const buffer = req.files.foo.data // data is the file buffer // foo is the key/file name
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', buffer);
     form.submit('example.org/upload', function(err, res) {
         res.send("done");
         //Do something here
     });
});
```

Comment: Just looked at it and it doesnt work as you said but the express-fileupload works so i would use that so you can even download the file uploaded (look at docs) but i couldnt get the form-data part to work you could look somewhere else or wait for someone to anwser. It depends where you want the file to be uploaded